# Send personal notification onUpdate condition

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like when a post is modified in the `category/{NeutralCategory}/{Posts}/{message}` tree and only if `finish` is validated, retrieve the`"UserID` of the post.
Go to the `users/UserID` tree to retrieve the "token" in order to send the notification to the person to let them know that the post is over.

If I test on firebase to send a notification manually with the token it works, so no worries on that side.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp();

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore
.document('category/{NeutralCategory}/{Posts}/{message}')
.onUpdate(async snapshot => {
  if (data.finish == previousData.finish) {
    return null;
    console.log("NON---------------------------------------------------");
  } else {    
    const database = admin.firestore();
    const messaging = admin.messaging();
    const message = snapshot.data();

    const data = change.after.data();
    const previousData = change.before.data();

        console.log("OUI---------------------------------------------------");    

        const sender = await database
            .collection('users')
            .doc(message.UserID)
            .get();

      const token = receiver.data().token;

       const payload = {
          notification: {
              title: `Nouveau message de ${sender.data().title}`,
              body: message.title,
              clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          }
      }
       return admin.messaging.sendToDevice(token, payload);
       console.log("FIN---------------------------------------------------");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your variables are not defined. On your first if statement, `data` and `previousData` are not defined.

Try this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

...

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore
  .document('category/{NeutralCategory}/{Posts}/{message}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, _) => {
    const data = change.after.data();
    const previousData = change.before.data();

    if (data.finish == previousData.finish) {
      console.log("NON---------------------------------------------------");
      return null;
    } else {
      const database = admin.firestore();

      console.log("OUI---------------------------------------------------");

      const sender = await database
        .collection('users')
        .doc(data.UserID)
        .get();

      console.log('sender', sender.data());
      const token = sender.data().token;
      console.log('token', token);

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: `Nouveau message de ${sender.data().title}`,
          body: data.title,
          clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        }
      }
      console.log("FIN---------------------------------------------------");
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I tried and I get this error: notifyNewMessage
ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `snapshot` . I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks ! but now I have this error: notifyNewMessage
TypeError: admin.messaging.sendToDevice is not a function

Comment: Please make sure this 3 lines exist at the top of your function (no duplicates): `const functions = require("firebase-functions");const admin = require("firebase-admin");const db = admin.firestore();` check the updated answer.

Comment: My answer have been updated to include them.

Comment: Yes I have those functions, I have admin.initializeApp(); above "const db = admin.firestore();" But it gives me the same error...

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Use this: `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);` instead of `admin.messaging.sendToDevice(token, payload);` Answer has been updated.

Comment: So glad I could help. You can also upvote the answer to make it easier for others to find.